Let answerers keep their rep for deleted questions that they had invested time and effort in
In the last month or so, an abnormally and extremely large number of my answers got deleted. There was no reason for deletion, it happened just because the question(s) with which my answer(s) were posted to was deleted for one reason or another. The "reasons" for the deletion of the questions range from duplicate, lacking debugging details or not clear (and if that's the case why did I manage to solve it?), or other reasons (none of them were off-topic, spam, or offensive).
They were all deleted by either moderators or (more often) experienced users. The point here is that, many of those answers that I posted got upvotes and some even got accepted.
I'm new to Stack Overflow and SE in general, so I hadn't made much contributions or gotten much reputation yet. Those answers were, if not the majority, at least a large portion of my contributions to SO. At least they were the better half of my answers. Losing them really hurts, and losing the reputation gained from them hurts even more.
I'm not accusing anyone here, but I feel like my feelings are being neglected when those people deleted the questions without even paying attention that there was an answer that got upvotes and (in some cases) accepted, even more so that they didn't realize the poor answerer that got affected was always a new contributor, me.
Now, after saying all that, I wish to propose a feature request so that all future new contributors will not suffer the same fate as me. Enhancing justice and fairness, I believe, should be of topmost priority on SE. After all, we all came here to learn from and help each other, and also to fairly and legitimately build up a good reputation to earn respect. So here's my proposal:
TL;DR: Basically put, my proposal suggests that for answerers who posted an answer to a question that got upvotes or accepted, let them keep the reputation points earned.
After the brief summary of my proposal, here's the full version. I elaborated on my original thoughts and tried to make this easy and achievable, but also fair and just. Of course, implementation of this suggestion requires some effort by the staff and the community, but I think the benefits brought about by such a system are definitely worth it.
Here's my proposal:
Let answerers who contributed to SE keep their reputation points even if the parent question is deleted, under the following circumstances:

The question was not deleted because of being spam, offensive, or blatantly off-topic (in these cases the answerer really shouldn't have answered, this should teach them a lesson).
The answer had a final net score > -3, i.e. for an answer to be eligible, it can have a minimum total net score of -2. (1 upvote - 5 downvotes = -4, reputation = 10 - 10 = 0. For answers with a net score of -4, there's no need for the extra pain here, since the answerer's rep will not be effected. In the case of net score = -3, reputation = 10 - 8, thus the user got 2 reputation from the answer, but considering -3 means that the answer is very likely not useful, and also that 2 reputation really isn't something to dwell on. An edit gives you 2 reputation.).
The answer does not have any offensive, spam, or very low quality flags on it (which means that bad answers do not qualify).
The question was not deleted by the answerer themselves (there's no reason for us to return the rep lost due to their own actions).
The answerer does not have an ongoing investigation of voting fraud or use of Generative AI (again, non-legitimate users should not have their rep retained).

If any one of the above conditions are not met, the answer will not be able to retain any reputation. However, if all of those conditions are met, then:

The answerer will retain any reputation earned from an answer to the question that is about to be deleted. This is regardless of:

The amount of time the answer had been on the site. The current 60 day restriction is not quite fair in this case.
The total net score, as long as it's above > -3. That is, the net score need not be > 3 as is the current case, and can even be negative so long as it's > -3 and got at least one upvote.

Also, for really great answers that got either 5 upvotes or a total net score >= 3, all downvotes should be removed while the upvotes and accepts remain. Yes, this is favoring, but for really great answers, a little reward does not harm anyone. For all other answers that do not meet this criteria (5 upvotes or a total net score >= 3), all positive and negative reputation changes will be retained.


Why this is beneficial
Firstly, answerers who had devoted their time and effort on answering a question should be awarded the reputation points. Taking the reputation away just because the parent question was deleted isn't fair. Of course, blatantly and clearly bad questions should not have been answered, and that's why I added the circumstance #1. However, for other deletion reasons, it's often subjective and not exact. Thus, if the answer did get upvote(s), that means the answerer is still worth awarding. It is not possible to completely eliminate wrongful deletions, so at least reduce the negative impact on innocent answerers. Secondly, all users will feel "more at home" if you will, and can use their knowledge to the fullest without thinking or fearing their contributions will be gone someday. Thirdly, this eliminates all chances of a user with high rep count to enact revenge in a especially harmful and subtle way; i.e., this eliminates the possibility of people trying to delete some person's post just for the answerer to lose rep. Although I do not have exact proof of such an occasion, I do have reason to believe that such a thing exists. Finally, this encourages high quality answers, with all answerers knowing that by contributing a great answer, their reputation and profile will clearly show the contributions they have made, and will not be effected by something they have no control over. Losing rep out of the blue just because of a (possibly wrongful) deletion of someone else's post is harmful to both the individual and the quality of answers.
In conclusion, I strongly recommend implementation of this system to ensure maximum fairness, justice, and quality of answers.

Note:
I do not intend to mean that all deletions are wrong or opinion-based. Most are valid, correct, legitimate and helpful. However, it is undeniable that a small percentage (say 5%) of deletions were mistakes. And this small percentage alone did a fairly large amount of negative impact on the answerer, asker, and the quality of answer, thus the community as a whole. By using my proposed system, we can mitigate these negative effects and reduce the harm to a minimum.

I hope this proposal is an improvement over my last one. I removed bad features, and explained this system a bit more. Please take a moment to read the entire proposal rather than downvoting just because it looks similar to my other, bad proposal. This is actually substantially different.

Specifically, I later realized that the deletion regulations and disagreement voting (Parts I and III of my of original post, if you had read it) are actually very bad ideas. Thus, I removed them in this improved version.

As a deleted answer explained, “This is already the case. Posts 60 days old at the time of deletion with a net score 3 or more, when deleted the author keeps their reputation.”  And I would remove even that. If a question is deleted, it means that, for one reason or another, it should not have been asked, and effort spent answering it was effort wasted that does not deserve credit.

@user3840170 Disagree. That's hostile to answerers, and will only result in more and more people deciding the "quantity over quality" as the only way to gain rep. Answerers are (in a way) more important than askers. Policy should help answerers.

Another thing to appreciate is that people care about maintaining quality standards over perceived hostility towards the answerer. Places without quality standards such as ours exist, but tend to have their own issues, such as poor quality and/or opinion-based content.

The current system already incentivises quantity over quality: answer hundreds or so of poor questions, and maybe some of them will slip through moderation for long enough that you’ll keep your reputation even when they’re cleaned up later.

@user3840170 That's what needs to be changed. To reduce the "quantity over quality" idea, we must let answerers believe that all good answers will get rewarded. No matter how strict a rule you impose on reputation earning, the "quantity over quality" answers will not stop.

This has been discussed in the past before. I'd highly recommend reading through the reasoning there and rebutting the arguments made there.

No, we need to establish that what is rewarded are good posts (and good ones only), not the other way around.

@user3840170 The point of the current retention rule is that if a post is considered within the site rules or helpful to others at the time it is posted, but later becomes unsuitable for factors beyond the poster's control (e.g., the site's scope changed, the technology in question changed, etc.), authors should be able to keep the reputation earned from the time it was useful/in scope, i.e., those changes beyond their control shouldn't be held against them. That's why the time part exists - it makes for a statute of limitations as it's called.

@SonictheAnonymousHedgehog I already read that post several times now, it's just nonsense. Every good answer a person contributes shall be rewarded, not just "as if it never happened". Then users who posted offensive content or spam should be able to delete their posts and say "the post's gone now, you should treat it as if it never happened", but in reality they did something harmful.

@SonictheAnonymousHedgehog Well, it’s a stupid rule anyway. It just lets poor posts off the hook as long as they slip through enforcement of already-existing standards for long enough, as described above. Also, Stack Exchange is supposed to be a long-term knowledge base, so obviously reputation should reflect the usefulness of one’s contribution in the long term, and not just what seemed good enough at the time.

@user3840170 Given that moderators now have a way to work around that (deleting a post with the plagiarism reason will not retain reputation), I don't think that's too much to worry about.

@SonictheAnonymousHedgehog As if moderators were the only ones doing moderation. Not only that, moderators generally refuse to remove posts for reasons of mere low quality, that’s entirely up to users – whose tactical “plagiarism” flags will surely be rejected.

"I do not intend to mean that all deletions are wrong or opinion-based" - sure, you intend to mean that all deletions that cause you to lose reputation are wrong or opinion-based. And with this I strongly disagree.

What is difficult to understand is that the First Class Citizen in SE Q&As are the Posts, not the humans. We humans in SE Q&As are categorized as moderators,and/or curators and/or content producers, whose goal is to build highest quality Q&A librares, where this content will generally be consumed and processed by automation tools(like lint, browser, LLM,...) and then reach the human reader. So if we start feeding our libraries with junk content and rewarding it, the tools that depend on our content will start to expel junk content, compromising dependent markets on that content.

Please read: Question Close Reasons - Definitions and Guidance and Why should I help close "bad" questions that I think are valid, instead of helping the OP with an answer?.

Side note: if you want to discuss specific posts you think were incorrectly deleted and why, that might be appropriate on Meta Stack Overflow (this one, for example, seems more like a misunderstanding than a "typo", though it could of course be a duplicate).

@user3840170 it's not nonsense really. It makes little sense to argue whether it is more fair to keep "grandfathered" rep or remove it because without keeping it site would simply break. I've been around when rep deletion was implemented many years ago and I observed how it was back then. Thing is, at first it was done the way you prefer - ie all rep from deleted questions was removed. But it soon became apparent that this way is going to harm the site in a major way because it frustrates too many important users...

...it turned out that some (many) useful contributors and curators are likely to leave because they felt this is unfair, and some will slip into destructive behavior like undelete-wars with a purpose to recover lost rep, and some will abstain of casting delete votes because of all that hassle involved, and so on, and so forth - and things are going to only get worse as long as we have it this way. So they were literally forced to change the initial approach to some compromise, just to avoid breaking the site

So it is not that somebody decided that keeping grandfathered rep is more fair and picked this approach but the other way 'round - it first turned out that deleting that rep doesn't work and because of that they changed to less dangerous way and the explanation given to current system is primarily there to help people understand how it makes some sense


The "reasons" for the deletion of the questions range from duplicate, lacking debugging details or not clear (and if that's the case why did I manage to solve it?), or other reasons (none of them were off-topic, spam, or offensive).
They were all deleted by either moderators or (more often) experienced users. The point here is that, many of those answers that I posted got upvotes and some even got accepted.

The questions you choose to answer tend to be ones that get deleted. If they are too vague for their answers to generate lasting value for anyone other than their askers, they tend to get deleted.
I recommend before answering, if they are downvoted or have comments pointing out significant problems with the question, perhaps refrain from answering the question seeing as your answer is more likely to be deleted along with the question.

I'm not accusing anyone here, but I feel like my feelings are being neglected when those people deleted the questions without even paying attention that there was an answer that got upvotes and (in some cases) accepted, even more so that they didn't realize the poor answerer that got affected was always a new contributor, me.

To put this bluntly, the purpose if the site is to maintain a high quality database of questions. We will not keep around extremely poor quality questions because someone will lose their reputation answering. If the question was closed as a duplicate, and the answer already exists, then the answer is of little value anyway.

The amount of time the answer had been on the site. The current 60 day restriction is not quite fair in this case.

Removing this would incentivize people speedily answering low quality, frequently asked duplicate questions before they get closed, and facilitate easy reputation farming. That 60 day restriction exists for a reason.

In my case, almost all the later deleted questions are originally upvoted, some more than one time. Also, the current model is causing exactly what you framed as the downside of my proposal: If even good quality answers get deleted just because the parent question is deleted, people will start to (or actually, already started) randomly throwing out a large number of low-quality answers, since it's not possible for every one of them to get deleted.

Garbage answers can be deleted regardless of question quality. Garbage questions take down good answers with them. The direct solution is do not answer garbage questions! and yet you continually reject this, the current implementation, because you are more concerned with imaginary internet points than real quality Q&A. At this point, refusing to respond to that, you are not acting in good faith. @LukeL

Laconic
If  a question was deleted, it was probably bad. If a user answers a bad question, they are hurting the site. If a user is hurting the site, they should not be rewarded for doing so.
The feature request
That's a really short answer to a really long post, which would do your feature request a disservice. I don't think that's fair, so I'm going to focus on some of the more specific arguments. I'm only going to focus on the last paragraph, since I don't think the methods are as important as the motivations.

Firstly, answerers who had devoted their time and effort on answering a question should be awarded the reputation points.

Reputation does not measure effort. It's (supposed to be) an indicator of a user's ability to contribute to this network meaningfully. If an answer does not contribute meaningfully to Stack Exchange's goals of creating a useful database, it should not earn reputation. Working hard on an answer does not entitle the poster to rep.

if the answer did get upvote(s), that means the answerer is still worth awarding.

Not all upvoted answers are good. Answering a question that should be deleted is actively harmful, even if the answer is correct. It makes this site noisier, interferes with our goal of creating a "library of detailed, high-quality answers," and prevents the Roomba from auto-deleting the question. None of those things should be rewarded.

all users will feel "more at home" if you will, and can use their knowledge to the fullest without thinking or fearing their contributions will be gone someday.

This change doesn't fix that. Restoring rep for answers to deleted questions doesn't undelete the answer. Their contribution will still be gone.

this eliminates all chances of a user with high rep count to enact revenge in a especially harmful and subtle way; i.e., this eliminates the possibility of people trying to delete some person's post just for the answerer to lose rep.

When has this happened? How often is it occurring? It seems rare enough to should be treated on a case-by-case basis instead.

this encourages high quality answers, with all answerers knowing that by contributing a great answer, their reputation and profile will clearly show the contributions they have made

No, it doesn't. It encourages people to answer questions that are about to get deleted. An answer like that doesn't provide any value because it's been deleted.

Losing rep out of the blue just because of a (possibly wrongful) deletion of someone else's post is harmful to both the individual and the quality of answers.

If the deletion is wrongful, there are ways to get that fixed. Asking on the site's meta or chat rooms (SOCVR, for example), casting undelete votes, and other processes can correct wrongful deletions. But in my experience, most deletions are deserved, so we should not prioritize the few bad deletions over the many good ones.

I strongly recommend implementation of this system to ensure maximum fairness, justice, and quality of answers.

The reputation system is already unfair. It's unfair because it creates perverse incentives to answer bad questions but doesn't reward those who vote to close them. This proposal would make the site more unfair to everyone who prioritizes the network's health over their own personal internet points.
Final thoughts
I understand the frustration associated with having an answer deleted. I have four answers that have been deleted that way myself. But those answers were bad for the site, and Stack Overflow is a better place without them. It doesn't matter that I lost out when they were deleted. The reputation system has to serve the network as a whole, not individual users.

You're just randomly picking everything I said and simply rejecting it. There's no real persuasive and constructive argument to effectively overthrow my proposal. Everyone here simply "rejects" and hates my proposal, but they don't seem to provide any alternative in resolving the issue I brought up, only rejecting that is was an issue in the first place.

@LukeL Okay then, what would be enough to "effectively overthrow your proposal?"

Introduce a system where there's absolutely no chance of accidentally answering a bad question.

@LukeL Your proposal does not do that. It does precisely the reverse.

Then please propose a system where there's absolutely no chance of accidentally answering a bad question.

@LukeL That's not how this works. This proposal would be actively harmful for this network and should be rejected in favor of what we have now. Whether there's a viable alternative solution doesn't change that. SE's not perfect, but we shouldn't make it worse.

"Then please propose a system where there's absolutely no chance of accidentally answering a bad question." the Staging Ground is a good start, though it still doesn't prevent anyone from answering on comment, but they won't get the rep either.

I have ignored the details of your proposal, because the proposal is motivated by profound misconceptions about Stack Exchange that render it moot.

In the last month or so, an abnormally and extremely large number of my answers got deleted.

I rather doubt there was anything abnormal or excessive about it, but of course you're entitled to your own perception and opinion.
If you find that questions you answer have a tendency to get deleted, this is, on balance, because you are answering questions that should be closed and deleted, and not answered. But yes, there is no way in the system to preserve your answer if the question is deleted.
The best defense is to understand the site's standards for questions, so that you can answer questions that meet those standards and are thus highly unlikely to be closed or deleted.
Please read:
https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask
https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer
https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions
What is a "closed" or "duplicate" question, and how does question closing work?
Why should I help close "bad" questions that I think are valid, instead of helping the OP with an answer?

There was no reason for deletion, it happened just because the question(s) with which my answer(s) were posted to was deleted for one reason or another.

You contradict yourself. There was a reason for deleting those questions, and therefore for deleting the answer.

The "reasons" for the deletion of the questions range from duplicate, lacking debugging details or not clear

So, you were told exactly the reason for deletion.

(and if that's the case why did I manage to solve it?)

It does not matter if you are able to read OP's mind. The purpose of questions on a Stack Exchange site is not to solve problems for the OPs, one at a time. The purpose of questions is to help build a reference Q&A library - so questions must be clear enough that other people with the same fundamental problem can clearly identify it in the question, and in particular they must be confident that it is not a different question that happens to be expressed using a lot of the same words.

or other reasons (none of them were off-topic, spam, or offensive).

So?

They were all deleted by either moderators or (more often) experienced users.

Yes, that's Stack Exchange working as designed.

The point here is that, many of those answers that I posted got upvotes and some even got accepted.

This does not matter even in the slightest.

I'm not accusing anyone here, but I feel like my feelings are being neglected when those people deleted the questions without even paying attention that there was an answer that got upvotes and (in some cases) accepted

Stack Exchange network sites are about the questions and answers themselves. They are not about the people who make those posts, or about whether they might feel bad about their content being judged unsuitable for the site.
The Code of Conduct exists so that people don't insult or harass each other, express bigotry etc. But it isn't actually there to protect your ego.

After all, we all came here to learn from and help each other, and also to fairly and legitimately build up a good reputation to earn respect.

No, that's not actually how Stack Exchange works. We're here to ask and answer questions in order to build up useful repositories of information, as described in each site's corresponding tour. Reputation is a flawed source of extrinsic motivation for that goal, provided because there apparently aren't enough people around who would do it just to see the end result. That's it.
